# plotting two arrays in python with one being filled with random numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two arrays `r_mod and gbp` in python after importing `matplotlib`. Array `r_mod` contains random numbers. When I plot the two array with the command `plt.plot(r_mod,gbp,"o")`, I get the first figure below which shows the global behavior of the relevant function stored in array `gbp`. However, when plotting with `plt.plot(r_mod,gbp)`, I get the second figure below which does not show the global behavior of the function.

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem ? I need to plot with `lines` not with `"o"` .

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for this is that matplotlib is ploting in order of first array. To solve this you need to sort first array.
Remember that the second table, if it is correlated with the first, must not be sorted, but the elements must be moved to their corresponding places from the new order of first array.